# summarize range with cell numbers given in cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two cells containing the range I want to sum. Is it possible to summarize this as in a vba macro?

I would like to do a simple summary of the values. This will give me a ?NAME error

Cells in excel
b2=11, c2=41

```
=SUM(range(cells(C2,2); cells(C2,2)))
```

Comment: Seems like you're trying to use VBA in a formula... that doesn't work. Are you writing a macro, or are you trying to enter a formula in a cell?

Comment: This is for a formula in a cell. I could of course do it as a macro. But I would like to do it directly in excel without any macros and loops if possible.

Comment: You are using C2 twice,  I assume the first `C2` should be `B2`?

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX:

```
 =SUM(INDEX(B:B,B2):INDEX(B:B,C2))
```

[image]

Comment: This looks interesting. Don't I need to use address also to use the column and row numbers?

Comment: No, `INDEX(B:B,B2):INDEX(B:B,C2)` will return the reference without the need for the volatile `ADRRESS` or `INDIRECT`

Answer (score 0):

`=SUM(B2:C2)`

This will sum those two cells.  Just expand the range if you want more.

Comment: Not what I am after.